# How to commit to antlr v2?

Tags: antlr, antlr2

For a personal project I had to use ANTLR v2 ... and seeing its output I decided to do some code smell removing in the source.

But now I just don't find any description on how I could commit back those changes.
Does anyone know where the ANTLR v2 sources are developed and how I could commit to that repo ?

The sources can be downloaded from http://www.antlr2.org/download.html ... but there is no mention on contribution.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This post seems off-topic because it's about committing to the off-site project.

Comment: You *had* to use ANTLR v2? Why? ANTLR2 is not actively being developed: any changes to the source would never find their way in a new release (because there will not be a new release anymore).

Comment: Yes, I'm switching to a newer version.
I was using v2 for a long time, I added some improvements in my version. I would like to make these improvements available for the community now.
If there is a way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ANTLR 2.7.7 is the final release of ANTLR 2. The source code for the release is available, but the development repository was taken offline years ago. There will not be any more official development on ANTLR 2, nor will there be any more releases.

I highly recommend you update to ANTLR 4, which is the current version of the toolset and is under active development.